# How do I iterate a loop over several data frames in a list in python

Tags: python-2.7, loops, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to programming and am working with Python.  For a work project I am trying to read several .csv files, convert them to data frames, concatenate some of the fields into one for a column header, and then append all of the dataframes into one big DataFrame.  I have searched extensively in StackOverflow as well as in other resources but I have not been able to find an answer.  Here is the code I have thus far along with some abbreviated output:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob 

# Read a directory of files to a list
csvlist = []
for f in glob.glob("AssayCerts/*"):
    csvlist.append(f)

csvlist  
['AssayCerts/CH09051590.csv', 'AssayCerts/CH09051591.csv', 'AssayCerts/CH14158806.csv', 'AssayCerts/CH14162453.csv', 'AssayCerts/CH14186004.csv']

# Read .csv files and convert to DataFrames
dflist = []
for csv in csvlist:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None, skiprows = 7)
    dflist.append(df)

dflist  
[                  0        1         2         3         4         5     \  
0                NaN  Au-AA23  ME-ICP41  ME-ICP41  ME-ICP41  ME-ICP41       
1             SAMPLE       Au        Ag        Al        As         B       
2        DESCRIPTION      ppm       ppm         %       ppm       ppm      

#concatenates the cells in the first three rows of the last dataframe; need to apply this to all of the dataframes.
for df in dflist:
    column_names = df.apply(lambda x: str(x[1]) + '-'+str(x[2])+' - '+str(x[0]),axis=0)

column_names  
0     SAMPLE-DESCRIPTION - nan  
1             Au-ppm - Au-AA23  
2            Ag-ppm - ME-ICP41  
3              Al-% - ME-ICP41
```

I am unable to apply the last operation across all of the DataFrames.  It seems I can only get it to apply to the last DataFrame in my list.  Once I get past this point I will have to append all of the DataFrames to form one large DataFrame.

Comment: You have some indentation issues (presumably one reason why you're getting downvoted). I think the issue is with the last part, you're assigning to `column_names` but only the last df gets assigned (the rest get written over) i.e. you're not appending to a list of changing `dflist`... presumably that's not your intention.

Answer (score 1):

As Andy Hayden mentions in his comment, the reason your loop only appears to work on the last DataFrame is that you just keep assigning the result of `df.apply( ... )` to `column_names`, which gets written over each time.  So at the end of the loop, `column_names` always contains the results from the last DataFrame in the list.

But you also have some other problems in your code. In the loop that begins `for csv in csvlist:`, you never actually reference `csv` - you just reference `filename`, which doesn't appear to be defined.  And `dflist` just appears to have one DataFrame in it anyway.

As written in your problem, the code doesn't appear to work.  I'd advise posting the real code that you're using, and only what's relevant to your problem (i.e. if building `csvlist` is working for you, then you don't need to show it to us).